# Selenium Webdriver- Charts testing- framework design(POM)

Tags: maven, selenium, highcharts

I am working on automating charts. There are 12 types of charts that I need to test. Once chart is created I am doing these validations :

1. Get x-axis, y-axis labels.
2. Get tooltips.
3. Get data labels.

There are multiple other validations too that are chart specific.
Charts are categorized majorly as 2d and 3d charts. 2d accept one parameter and 3d accept 2 parameters.

I analysed :

1. X-axis and y-axis label cssLocator is same for all charts.
2. For getting tooltip, shape is different in every chart so I need to pass is as parameter like in some chart its circle, rectangular, path.

I have designed it like this:

1. Create ChartUtil class that contains all reusable functions.
2. Created function createchart() and overloaded it. 1 function accepts 2 parameter and 1 accepts 3 parameter.

createChart(String parameter1, String dataseries) 
createChart(String parameter1, String dataseries, String parameter2)
    switch(parameter1)
    {
    case(X):
   statement;
   case(Y):
   statement;
   case(Z):
   statement;
    }

//dataseries is css locator for tooltip shape as its different for different charts.

Now: For example, take BarChart class. There is parameter document type that has 3 values say A,B,C. There are 3 parameters that i need to check say X,Y,Z. So there are 9 combinations for each chart class like:

```
select(A);
createChart("X", "tooltip_Barchart");
createChart("Y", "tooltip_Barchart");
createChart("Z", "tooltip_Barchart");

select(B);
createChart("X", "tooltip_Barchart");
createChart("Y", "tooltip_Barchart");
createChart("Z", "tooltip_Barchart");
```

and so on. And there are 12 classes. There are multiple conditions that are specific to these charts but all are checked in ChartUtil class. Functionality is working fine. Is there any other way i can design this more efficiently. 
I thought of using Data Provider but i am not able to apply it in my scenario as every class calls createchart() function 9 times. So is there any better way to club all these 11 classes efficiently.

Thanks,
Garvita Girotra